# Issue with PostgreSQL Automated Backups in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, backup, google-cloud-sql

**Hi All**

I have been trying to schedule automated backup in a PostgreSQL instance in GCP. I have set the REST API payload as directed in : 
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backing-up#schedulebackups

But the problem is that when I verify the backup schedule on console for the instance, it does not show any backup window time there. Only the timezone conversion is visible.

This is my request Payload :

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/myProjectID/instances/test1
{
  "settings":
  {
    "backupConfiguration":
    {
      "startTime": "11:30",
      "enabled": true,
      "pointInTimeEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

**The following is the affected information in my screen in console :**

> test1
>   PostgreSQL master
>   Backup settings
>   Automated backups 
>   Enabled
>   Backup time 
>   (UTC+5:30)

**As opposed to the information in screen when I select the schedule time from console :**

> test1
>   PostgreSQL master
>   Backup settings
>   Automated backups 
>   Enabled
>   Backup time   
>   11:30 AM — 3:30 PM (UTC+5:30)

**Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? My objective is to make sure the scheluded backup occurs at my intended time mentioned in my REST request payload.**

Comment: I think...unless I'm mistaken...those are the same thing? In your payload, you're specifying 11:30 (local time for REST calls by default I believe).

It's a little strange that it's showing you UTC+5:30, but UTC+5:30 is 11:30 if you're in MST? I think?

Comment: @GabeWeiss : It shows the same Backup time (UTC+5:30) (and nothing else) in console no matter what startTime I specify in my REST call.

Comment: I see what you're saying now... if I change the request JSON times, it DOES update the local time representation in the console, but the UTC time does not change. I think that's a bug in the display but I'll verify with the team. I haven't left time enough to verify if it's doing the right thing, but I suspect it is.

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed now. :)
I have repeated the same activity today and now I am able to see the Backup time reflecting on the console depending upon the start time specified in my REST call.
Thanks for helping @GabeWeiss